# what is going on in std::function operator() and std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std-function, perfect-forwarding

I was looking at the `std::function` implementation and its call `operator()`

```
template<typename Ret, typename... ArgTypes>
Ret function< Ret (ArgTypes...)>::operator()(ArgTypes...args) const
{
  // some stuff
  return invoker(functor, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
}
```

I was particularly wondering, why it uses `std::forward` here? Does this anything have to do with perfect forwarding?
Because perfect forwarding could only be done if `operator()`  is a template with a variadic template declaration `template<typename... Args>` (which it is not, *the declaration is a partial specialization of std::function*).
What is the intention of using std::forward here? I am confused :-)?

Comment: ‘*which it is not*’ Isn't it? Sure looks like it to me.

Comment: the declaration is a full specialization of std::function, and the templ. params  `Ret,  ArgTypes` are already fixed

Comment: Looks like a member function of a partial specialization of a class template to me. I'm not sure where you see a full specialization(full specialization would have empty template parameter list).

Comment: @ Dmitry Kuznetsov You are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that this is not your typical "perfect forwarding" scenario.  A brief example can help illustrate the motivation.  Assume a type `A` with instrumented constructors and destructor:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    A a1{1};
    A a2{2};
    std::function<void(A, A&)> f{[](A x, A& y){}};
    f(a1, a2);
}
```

This will output:

```
A(int state): 1
A(int state): 2
A(A const& a): 1
A(A&& a): 1
~A(1)
~A(-1)
~A(2)
~A(1)
```

Explanation:

`a1` and `a2` are constructed on the stack.  Then when passed into the `function` invoker, `a1` is first copied to bind to the first by-value parameter, and then `std::forward<A>` is called on `a1` which *moves* it from the by-value parameter into the lambda.

In contrast, `a2` need not be copied to bind to the `function` `A&` parameter, and then `std::forward<A&>(a2)` is called, which forwards `a2` as an lvalue instead of rvalue, and this binds to the `A&` parameter of the lambda.

Then things get destructed.  The `~A(-1)` indicates the destruction of an `A` in a move-constructed-from state with this instrumented `A`.

In summary, even though `ArgTypes` isn't deduced as in the usual perfect forwarding idiom, we still want to forward by-value `ArgTypes` as rvalues, and by-reference `ArgTypes` as lvalues.  So `std::forward` just happens to do exactly what we want here.

Comment: @Gabriel:  Sorry, I don't understand the followup question.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: Can one formulate it also like that (for me a bit more clear):
...and then ``std::forward<A>(a1)`` is called which returns `A&&a1` (which is a rvalue reference -> moves it into the lambda).

...and then `std::forward<A&>(a2)` is called, which returns `A&  && a2` which collapses to `A& a2` (which is a lvalue reference, -> forwarding as an lvalue).

Comment: @Gabriel:  `std::function` **is** formulated as I describe above.  If that is what "that" means in your question, then it is already that way in the standard.  Sorry if I'm being dense.  I've been awake for too many hours at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused by many things here.

First, perfect forwarding has nothing to do with variadic templates. You could create a wrapper class that has a function that takes one argument and forward it to the wrapped object :

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    template<typename Arg>
    decltype(auto) test(Arg&& arg) {
        return t.test(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

    T t;
};
```

Notice the use of perfect forwarding here without any variadic templates. If `t.test` would require a move only type as parameter, it would not be possible to call it without the `forward<Arg>(arg)`.

---

The second thing happening here is the parameter not being followed by `&&`. Adding `&&` to `ArgTypes` would be a mistake and would make some cases fail to compile. Consider this simple case :

```
std::function<void(int)> f;
int i = 0;
f(i);
```

That would fail to compile. If you add `&&` to `ArgTypes`, every parameters that are not reference (eg. `int`) would become an rvalue reference on the call operator (in our case, `int&&`). Since all parameter types are already qualified correctly in the `std::function` argument list, what you want to recieve in the call operator is exactly those types, not transformed.

The why you need `std::forward` if you don't use `&&`? Because even though you don't need to infer value categories, you still need to not copy every arguments to the contained function. If one of the `std::function`'s parameter is `int&`, you don't want to move it. But if one of the parameter is `std::unique_ptr<int>`, you must move it! And this is exactly what `std::forward` is for. Moving only what should be moved.

Answer (score 0):

`std::forward` just appends rvalue reference to the type, so taking reference collapsing rules into account, it effectively passes reference arguments as-is and moves the object arguments.